# Anyway to send data from Node-Red to Google Spread sheet for storing in table as dtb?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, node-red

I'm try to put telemetry data from node red to google sheet for monitoring and stored as dtb. In the past I can create google form and used it as http request to put data to sheet. But now google form has changed link form that i can't use it anymore. Thanks

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply. I just use this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/node-red/IO3I0PI_u2g 1
but I need to change some part of url for http request. The new one of google form link has change but we can use old form like in that link and I can find the entityid by looking at parameter from network monitor function in browser :grin: